# Replacement of deprecated textTheme in flutter

Tags: flutter

I am a newbie in Flutter, and still getting familiar with terms and properties of it. Anyways, when I am using `textTheme`, and mention any property like `title`, `button` etc. it shows that the property is deprecated and shouldn't be used anymore. My assumption is `textTheme` is only deprecated, so what should I replace it with, so that it is not deprecated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For `title`, you need to use  `subtitle1` instead.

You can see the deprecated list from **TextTheme** source code in `text _theme.dart`. If you're using IntelliJ, you can view the source code by right-clicking the `title` property, then select **Go To** **->** **Declaration or Usages**.

Here the excerpts for deprecated properties of [`text _theme.dart`](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/commit/79a43be22abeed2e184beb5009bd506bd47fb436#diff-3fc83a1fd3402b44f7cf1fb24fb544bdb5ba923f0db4547f2561263a2c8873b7):

```
@Deprecated(
  'This is the term used in the 2014 version of material design. The modern term is headline1. '
  'This feature was deprecated after v1.13.8.'
)
TextStyle? display4,
@Deprecated(
  'This is the term used in the 2014 version of material design. The modern term is headline2. '
  'This feature was deprecated after v1.13.8.'
)
TextStyle? display3,
@Deprecated(
  'This is the term used in the 2014 version of material design. The modern term is headline3. '
  'This feature was deprecated after v1.13.8.'
)
TextStyle? display2,
@Deprecated(
  'This is the term used in the 2014 version of material design. The modern term is headline4. '
  'This feature was deprecated after v1.13.8.'
)
TextStyle? display1,
@Deprecated(
  'This is the term used in the 2014 version of material design. The modern term is headline5. '
  'This feature was deprecated after v1.13.8.'
)
TextStyle? headline,
@Deprecated(
  'This is the term used in the 2014 version of material design. The modern term is headline6. '
  'This feature was deprecated after v1.13.8.'
)
TextStyle? title,
@Deprecated(
  'This is the term used in the 2014 version of material design. The modern term is subtitle1. '
  'This feature was deprecated after v1.13.8.'
)
TextStyle? subhead,
@Deprecated(
  'This is the term used in the 2014 version of material design. The modern term is subtitle2. '
  'This feature was deprecated after v1.13.8.'
)
TextStyle? subtitle,
@Deprecated(
  'This is the term used in the 2014 version of material design. The modern term is bodyText1. '
  'This feature was deprecated after v1.13.8.'
)
TextStyle? body2,
@Deprecated(
  'This is the term used in the 2014 version of material design. The modern term is bodyText2. '
  'This feature was deprecated after v1.13.8.'
)
```

Answer (score 1):

[image]

> textTheme is deprecated and shouldn't be used. This property is no
> longer used, please use toolbarTextStyle and titleTextStyle instead.
> This feature was deprecated after v2.4.0-0.0.pre.

> **Solution**
>
> Use **toolbarTextStyle**

```
  appBarTheme: AppBarTheme(
      color: Colors.white,
      elevation: 0.0,
      iconTheme: IconThemeData(color: Colors.black),
      toolbarTextStyle: Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodyText2,
      titleTextStyle: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline6)),
```

Answer (score 0):

Following ישו אוהב אותך's answer, and reading properly the documentation he or she kindly shared, you need to substitute **title** by **headline6**, not subtitle1.